# How to create a shape in the UV image editor for using as a mask in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, uv-image-editor, masking

I'm using Blender for editing desktop recordings that I make using Open Broadcaster software.

I would like to highlight areas of the screen to draw attention to them by surrounding them with a red rectangular box.

I've created a previous post that asks: [How to highlight areas of a desktop recording in video sequence editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58969/how-to-highlight-areas-of-a-desktop-recording-in-video-sequence-editor)

The answer to that post is fantastic, and I would like to now understand how to create an image in the UV editor for using as the mask. How can I do this?

I'm a complete Blender noob and have not used any part of Blender except for the VSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is split a screen and open a *UV/Image Editor*, or just open one up through the bottom, lefthand icon:

[image]

Load in an image with the *Open* button (you can screenshot a frame of your video) so that you know where to put your mask.

[image]

Still in the footer of the *UV/Image Editor*, add switch from *View* mode to *Mask* mode.

[image] --> [image]

Add a new mask:

[image]

Now there are three keys to remember:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> adds a *Control Point* where you click.
2. Once you have three or more points, use <kbd>A</kbd> to select all/deselect all.
3. If every point is selected (yellow), use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to connect the points.